# Please be sure of your migrations

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/480007/i-made-wordpress-multisite-and-now-everything-doesnt-display-properly?noredirect=1) was migrated to the wrong Stack Exchange site by the Super User community. This isn't the only community mis-migration I have encountered and tried to clean up.

I have flagged this for Moderator attention, but it really shouldn't come to this.

If you're not *absolutely* sure that your Migration target is the right place, **don't Migrate!**

From the Web Apps FAQ:

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Desktop software
> - Applications for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - **Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB**
> - Web applications containing adult content
> - Developing web applications
> - Browsers and their features
> - App recommendations unless prior research is shown

(Yes, I understand there may be some confusion, since questions about **wordpress.com** are fair game on Web Apps.)

When you Migrate to the wrong site you make a *lot* of work for Moderators to clean up.

Comment: Link to question?

Comment: The very first word is linked to the question. But here it is again: http://superuser.com/questions/480007/i-made-wordpress-multisite-and-now-everything-doesnt-display-properly?noredirect=1

Comment: I don't think this has done by multiple users from what I can see, but I might be wrong. Anyhow it's very interesting that [the history is quite a mess](http://superuser.com/posts/480007/revisions) and as Sathya has mentioned on the question it appears there is some bug there. If you can still access the question at Web Apps you might be able to figure out at which time the question got migrated...

Comment: @Tom: I went back through my flags and you're right. The other mis-migration I was thinking of came from a different site. _Mea culpa_. However, mis-migrations like this cause a lot of headaches and I think the advice is still valid.

Comment: Indeed, works well as a reminder to check the target's site FAQ when in doubt.

Comment: @TomWijsman the revision history doesn't say so(the migration history to webapps was cleared prior to migrating to WordPress), but the question did get migrated from [su] via 5 VtC votes.